# Generic math operator overloading without copying

Tags: generics, math, rust

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42404227/generic-math-without-copying-in-rust), I'll have a similar question about overloading math operators.

Considering this code basis, which assumes that `T` objects can be added by value and gives a `O`:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct NoCopy<T>(T);

impl<T: Add<Output = O>, O> Add for NoCopy<T> {
    type Output = NoCopy<O>;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        NoCopy(self.0 + other.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = NoCopy::<isize>(5);
    let b = NoCopy::<isize>(3);

    let _c = a + b;
}
```

I would like to provide with one implementation of the Add trait to work on `&NoCopy<T>` and provide a `NoCopy<O>` instance, making the assumption that Add operator is provided for `&T` (and gives a `O`). `T` would not require to respect the `Copy` trait.

But I can't figure out how to write it, especially the generics bindings.

```
impl<???> Add for &NoCopy<T> {
    type Output = NoCopy<O>;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        NoCopy(&self.0 + &other.0)
    }
}
```

What the missing part (`???`) would look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can put a lifetime constraint on `&T`:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a, O> Add for &'a NoCopy<T>
where
    &'a T: Add<Output = O>,
{
    type Output = NoCopy<O>;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        NoCopy(&self.0 + &other.0)
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8559b7daa352df84a99391f893d7a564))